# Jquery + load a certain div on all pages that are open in browser

Tags: jquery

I have a fancybox popup window..
When a link is clicked an Ajax request is generated. This works fine..

Here's the question: Is it possible to adjust all divs with id as "counter" in all the pages that are open in the user's browser?

I have 4 pages with an id of "counter". I want the counter to be updated on all open pages when the user clicks the link..

My code looks like this:

```html
   <div id="<?php echo $id ?>">
    <?php if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){ ?>
 <p class="added" style="float:right">Added to your Bookshelf</p>
    <?php } else{ ?>
    <p class="add"  style="cursor:pointer">BUY</p>
    <?php } ?>
    </div><!--buybutton-->

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```